# Node npm why all the modules are installed in the root node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

In the past when you installed npm module, all the modules that this module depends on were installed in this module folder under npm_modules folder, but now all the modules are installed in the root node_modules folder, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you have updated your npm?
Cause, according to docs, they featured flattening in v3.5.0: ["Only your direct dependencies will show in node_modules and everything they depend on will be flattened in their node_modules folders"](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

**Global libraries**

You can run *npm list -*g to see where global libraries are installed.

On *nix systems they are normally placed in /usr/local/lib/node or /usr/local/lib/node_modules when installed globally. If you set the NODE_PATH environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.

**Non-global libraries**

Non-global libraries are installed the node_modules subfolder in the folder you are currently in.

You can run *npm list* to see the installed non-global libraries for your current location.

You can verify by running npm config get prefix
Depending on that output you may want to change where global packages get installed. 
Hope I was able to give insight and possible help.
Cheers!